# Alter image output in content

Tags: images, filters, hooks

I'm trying to implement the [JAIL javascript](https://github.com/sebarmeli/JAIL/blob/master/src/jail.js) into my WordPress install. The javascript requires me to add a data-attribute and change the output html of images.

I have been looking through the codex for filters or hooks that can help me, but i can't find anything. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: This is really dependent on your theme, there are just to many ways it can be outputting images.

Comment: I'm think of the images added inside the "writing area". Those inside "the_content".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your better off adding your custom image data when you insert it into a post using `media_send_to_editor`, the caveat is this will not be applied to any existing images, only ones inserted after adding the function.

To apply it to to existing content you will have use  `preg_match` on `the_content` filter, but this can significantly slow your site down, it is advised you don't parse the output like this.

A `media_send_to_editor` example:

```
function WPSE_78285_Mime($html, $id) {

    //fetching attachment by post $id
    $attachment = get_post($id); 
    $mime_type = $attachment->post_mime_type;

    //get an valid array of images types   
    $image_exts = array( 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpe', 'image/gif', 'image/png' );

    //checking the above mime-type
    if (in_array($mime_type, $image_exts)) { 

        // the image link would be great
        $src = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );

        // enter you custom output here, you will want to probably change this
        $html = '<a href="' . $src .  '" class="your-class" data-src="/img/image1.jpg" rel="your-rel"><img src="'. $src .'" /></a>';
        return $html; // return new $html    
    }
        return $html;
}

add_filter('media_send_to_editor', 'WPSE_78285_Mime', 20, 2);
```